# Update an email id using PHP

Tags: php, logic, email, catch-all

Is there a way in PHP to update an email id in a mail server if we have the access details of the mail server. The requirement is as follows.
I am developing a community website which need a provision to upload photos to their photo gallery by sending an email. We planned to create email id for each user so that they could send emails with photo attachments to that id. A cron job will search for emails inside those id's and if it finds a mail with attachment, uploads the file to the server and subject of the email will be considered as the photo caption.

But it has a security loophole such that anyone who knows the email id can send an email and add photo to others account. We are planning to have a security code in their id which can be modified by user if required.

eg. name.XXXX@domain.com where XXXX is a four digit secret code. THe user can change that code whenever required. i.e. the email id can be name.1234@domain.com or name.3452@domain.com according to the user's wish to maintain privacy. So is there a way to edit the email id using PHP functions.

Comment: It is impossible to help you without details on the mail daemon you are using.

Comment: You can create virtual mailboxes using Postfix, DoveCot, and MySQL, where the email account information is kept in MySQL without every having to create a "real" account on the system for the user. With this setup, changing an address is a simple matter of updating the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating email accounts and/or aliases would certainly be possible with PHP, but it would depend so much on your server setup.

Another route to consider would be to not have any real email boxes, but to instead have all email delivered to a catch-all account and have your cron script search through that one mailbox and compare all recipient addresses against a database, then you don't have to worry about actually creating real email users on the server.

Additionally, in terms of improving security, you could have each user authenticate which sender email addresses are allowed to send emails with photo attachments. It's still not bullet-proof, because sender addresses can be spoofed, but it's an extra step in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the support. and it is a very good turnaround.. I will create a catchall email id and allow users to edit their secret numbers in the email. So whenever and email comes(eg. name.1234@domain.com ), instead of bouncing, it will move to the catch all account. We can cross check it fromt he db with the name and secret code, if it is correct, do the remaining logic.. :)